# lsqnonlin matlab vs least_squares python - bounds parameter different behavior

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, least-squares

I am trying to convert some code **from matlab to python**.
The matlab code includes the function `lsqnonlin` which solve a non linear least square problem.
I have searched for a similar function in python and found `least_squares` from `scipy.optimize`.
By the documentation this is the right function to use.

I have tried the function with some different inputs and was glad with the result - same as matlab.
Then i found an input that giving different output from matlab vs python.
After i investigate the case i understood the problem.

Bounds parameter behavior is different between python `least_squares` and matlab `lsqnonlin`.
In python the Bounds parameter is for the x0 value (the function input) in matlab the bounds parameter (lb and ub) are for the output of the function.

**So my problem is when a point from x0 not in bounds.**

I will specify the problem with parameters:

- x0 - [1,2,16]
- lb - [0,1,50]
- ub - [2,3,65]

The third item is not in bounds. ***Python wont run the function while matlab will run the function and will give output.***

More information:

- A Quote from the matlab doc when x0 is out of bound:

> Components of x0 that violate the bounds lb ≤ x ≤ ub are reset to the
>   interior of the box defined by the bounds.

i cant figure it out what is the interior of the box, i have tried change the values to the lb without success.
maybe the solution to my problem is to understand this line.

- Running without bounds (default value for bound(-inf,inf)) - same results matlab and python.
- When running x0 in bounds - same results matlab and python.
- I have tried other methods from different libraries with no success.

links for documentation:

1. matlab - https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html
2. python - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html

i will be glad for some advises, some ideas or a solution.

Comment: This observation is astonishing! I was expecting an *infeasible parameter* error (+ I thought that I had already experienced some...) Nevertheless, I have no idea what your actual question/problem is. Can you sharpen this a bit more?

Comment: Thnks for your answer. My problem is that matlab and python does not have the same behavior for the same input. When x0 is not in bounds, python throws infeasible error when matlab knows how to handle the infeasible state. I need to understand how the matlab handle the infeasible state. Thnks again!

Comment: I guess, your explanation is correct: Matlab applies the box-constraints on the result. That means that you can start outside this box as long as the model is feasible on this point. After the first iteration, the output is forced into the box

Comment: do you know how the output is forced into the bounds? i want to adapt same behavior for python and matlab?

Comment: check out the documentation. `lsqnonlin` is a trust-region reflective algorithm (in fact, it implements the algorithm of *Coleman and Li* http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S1052623494240456), i.e. it reflects the values at the constraints